# How to hide menu bar in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I mean it hides automatically, but I can still see it as a white line in the bottom which is annoying in fullscreen mode. Is there any way to completely remove it from the screen? I still can reach it with ctrl + home, so I don't need it to popup on mouse hover

Answer (score 3):

Open the command prompt, navigate to the folder where vboxmanage is and execute the code below.

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations noMenuBar,noStatusBar
```

Comment: I do not recommend this because it is a permanent setting on VirtualBox. To undo run: "VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations".

Comment: Hey Diego. I think it depends on user's preference. I still prefer it to be "permanent settings". and then I made a small gui app with checkbox to toggle the showing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fool with VBoxManage if you'd rather use CLI. If you launch your VM with the VBoxSDL command, then the VM is displayed in a simple window without any pretty icons.

VBoxSDL --startvm

Reference:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#vboxsdl

Comment: VBoxSDL is not available on the Mac OS X host platform